# Percentile rank in pyspark using QuantileDiscretizer

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, quantile

I am wondering if it's possible to obtain the result of `percentile_rank` using the `QuantileDiscretizer` transformer in pyspark.

The purpose is that I am trying to avoid computing the `percent_rank` over the entire column, as it generates the following error:

```
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! 
Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

The method I am following is to first use `QuantileDiscretizer` then normalize to [0,1]:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.ml.feature import QuantileDiscretizer
from scipy.stats import gamma

X1 = gamma.rvs(0.2, size=1000)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(X1, columns=["x"]))

df = df.withColumn("perc_rank", F.percent_rank().over(Window.orderBy("x")))
df = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=df.count()+1,\
                         inputCol="x",\
                         outputCol="q_discretizer").fit(df).transform(df)

agg_values = df.agg(F.max(df["q_discretizer"]).alias("maxval"),\
                    F.min(df["q_discretizer"]).alias("minval")).collect()[0]

xmax, xmin = agg_values.__getitem__("maxval"), agg_values.__getitem__("minval")
normalize = F.udf(lambda x: (x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin))

df = df.withColumn("perc_discretizer", normalize("q_discretizer"))
df = df.withColumn("error", F.round(F.abs(F.col("perc_discretizer")- F.col("perc_rank")),6) )
print(df.select(F.max("error")).show())
df.show(5)
```

However, it seems that increasing the number of datapoints the error grows, so I am not sure this is the right way to do it.

Is it possible to use `QuantileDiscretizer` to obtain the percentile_rank?

Alternatively is there a way to compute `percentile_rank` over an entire column in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the below to avoid the warning message:

```
X1 = gamma.rvs(0.2, size=10)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(X1, columns=["x"]))
df = df.withColumn("dummyCol", F.lit("some_val"))
win = Window.partitionBy("dummyCol").orderBy("x")
df = df.withColumn("perc_rank", F.percent_rank().over(win)).drop("dummyCol")
```

but nonetheless, the data would still be moved to a single worker, I don't think so there is any better alternative to avoid the shuffle here since the complete column needs to be rank-ordered.

In case you have multiple windows over the same column, you can try to pre-partition the data and then apply the ranking functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Nonetheless, this would be equivalent to have a single partition, apart for the warning error. Anyhow, I think your idea of pre-partitioning it's interesting...instead of `F.lit("some_val")` one could set a partition index

Comment: Yep, honestly I think that is useful only if you are working very large datasets or there is a budget cap on resources or both, otherwise not worth the hassle.

Comment: Anyhow, even if I partition data, the problem is that the percent_rank would find each percentile only inside each partition, while it should look inside each partitions to compute the value correctly